# Windows 7 - Windows Update failing - Error code 80071A91

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit installation where Windows Update has stopped working for no apparent reason.

6 new important updates are listed as available. No matter whether I try to install all of them or just a subset, it always goes like so:

1. Updates are being downloaded.
2. One update after the other is reported as being installed. ("Update x of n is being installed ...")
3. After the last update has been "installed", the Windows Update icon turns red and it is stated that none of the updates were installed. (I.e. if I tried to install 6 updates, it says "6 updates failed to install.". An error code of 80071A91 is reported.

When googling for this error code, I found advice to delete files in %windir%\system32\config\txr and %windir%\system32\SMI\Store\Machine. Unfortunately, this didn't help.

What can I do? Any log file I can check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How-to reset the File System Resource Manager if you receive error 0x80071A91

1. Click <kbd>Start</kbd> click <kbd>All Programs</kbd> click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and select **Run as administrator**.
2. In the Command Prompt window you will need to type the following: `fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Note: You will need to replace the C:\ with the drive letter that Windows 7 is installed on.
4. Restart your computer, and then attempt to install the failed update(s).

As always you can try the [Microsoft FixIt Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058/en-us).

Comment: I already tried that numerous times, to not effect.

Comment: Check updated post

Comment: I tried this FixIt tool. It didn't work either. It said it fixed it, but it didn't.

Comment: Read this, http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/97775-update-error-80070643-a.html#post845289

Comment: You should probably also run an SFC to be on the safe side - **in an Elevated Command Prompt window, type** 
`SFC /SCANNOW`

Comment: sfc says it found damaged system files it could not repair. For details, I should look at CBS.log. There are a few Error entries in there containing STATUS_RM_NOT_ACTIVE. What's that mean? What should I look for in this log file? Btw, this Windows installation is rather new. I only installed it a few weeks ago.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6853/discussion-between-james-young-and-tajmahal)

Comment: After clicking Upgrade, setup is telling me that it can't proceed as the version I am trying to install over is newer than the version on the DVD. :-( I did everything as stated in http://www.w7forums.com/repair-install-t1204.html

Comment: Ok, luckily I found a SP1 disc. Now it's installing.

Comment: Doing a repair install (upgrade install) actually fixed the problem. I would have wished for a method less brutal to work, but that was the only measure that helped. I'll mark this answer as accepted because the discussion with @James Young (in chat) lead me to finally perform a repair install. Thanks again!

Comment: This command line resolved an issue with a relative's Windows 8 computer. As a programmer I wonder how the machine got into this state. This command resets NTFS metadata so I wonder if there was inconsistency due to a power failure, or the machine getting switched off before all updates were applied.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing them one at a time, starting with the oldest (lowest numbered).  Sometimes updates can conflict, both trying to update the same files, causing them to fail.

Comment: I also tried that. Did not work.

Comment: Did you reboot after each one (even if it didn't ask)?

Comment: I tried both with and without rebooting. It didn't want to install a single one of them. I guess I have rebooted this machine aprox. 50 times today while trying to figure out the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible strategy is suggested by [dockster in sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/97775-update-error-80070643-a.html):

```
1) Turn Windows Features On/Off --> Uncheck .Net Framework 3.5
2) Run Windows Update Reset Tool (Fix it) [Check "Aggressive Mode"] Article
3) Run .Net Cleanup Tool Article
4) In an elevated command prompt, execute (Article):

   1. Bring up an elevated (Administrator) command prompt
   2. Execute the following commands sequentially:
      a. fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\
      b. cd %windir%\system32\config\txr 
      c. attrib -r -s -h *
      d. del *
   3.Type: Cd c:\windows\System32\SMI\Store\Machine
     Type: Attrib –a –h –s *.TM*
     Type: Del *.TM*
     *** You may get access denied errors -- its ok for now ***

5) Restart in Safe Mode with Command Prompt. Redo the steps above in BOLD. Some files still will not delete. That's fine.
6) Restart in Normal Mode - run windows update with success.
```

Comment: I have already done that, to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was just having that error in my Win 7, no amount of resetting things fixed it.

I ran the FSUTIL command above. Then I read the explanation above of what that command does. So I figured I'd also run a CHKDSK, and that actually found some corrupt attributes and restored a few orphaned files.

Then I ran Windows Update again and the two remaining updates completed. So for me either the FSUTIL or the CHKDSK repaired me.